# Kivy .kv design issue

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, kivy-language

and thank you in advance.

I'm looking to design a screen in kivy that just has some accounts in MDCards. I can not for the life of me get these MDCard designs to work cleanly. The ideal functionality of this screen would be to have the title 'Accounts' in the top left. With scrollable 2 columns of MDCards (which is dynamically long - this part I've done, I think). What I'm struggling with is that the MDCards have large gaps in between the larger MDCard title labels, and the rest of the account data. I've attached a screenshot of what is going on (it should be pretty clear), and also my .kv file.

I'm not sure if I should be starting from the most child element for sizing or the root element and working from there. I want it to be dynamic based on the screen someone is using as much as possible.

[image: Screenshot of Accounts Screen with large gap in MDCards]

```
#:kivy 2.1.0


<AccountWidget>:
   
    
    MDCard:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        elevation: 2
        radius: 0
        md_bg_color: [0, 1, 0, 1]
        
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            rows: 1
            cols_minimum: {0: self.parent.width * 0.1, 1: self.parent.width * 0.90}
           

            MDLabel:
                id: account_id_variable
                markup: True
                text: f'[size=25][b]{root.id_label}[/b][/size]'
                halign: 'center'
                valign: 'top'
                font_size: sp(22)
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 30
                
            MDLabel:
                id: name
                markup: True
                text: f'[size=25][b]{root.name_label}[/b][/size]'
                halign: 'center'
                valign: 'top'
                font_size: sp(22)
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 30
        
        GridLayout:
            cols: 4
            cols_minimum: {0:self.parent.width*0.15,1:self.parent.width*0.35,2:self.parent.width*0.15,3:self.parent.width*0.35}
       
    
            MDLabel:
                id: type_text
                markup: True
                text: 'Type: '           
                halign: 'center'
                font_size: sp(12)
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 30
                

            MDLabel:
                id: type_variable
                markup: True
                text: f'{root.type_label}'          
                halign: 'center'
                bold: True
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 30

            MDLabel:
                id: owner_text
                markup: True
                text: 'Owner: '            
                halign: 'center'
                font_size: sp(12)
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 30

            MDLabel:
                id: owner_variable
                markup: True
                text: f'{root.owner_label}'       
                halign: 'center'
                bold: True
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 30

            MDLabel:
                id: joint_text
                markup: True
                text: 'Joint: '    
                halign: 'center'
                font_size: sp(12)
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 30

            MDLabel:
                id: joint_variable
                markup: True
                text: f'{root.joint_label}'
                halign: 'center'    
                bold: True
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 30

            MDLabel:
                id: bank_text
                markup: True
                text: 'Bank: '               
                halign: 'center'
                font_size: sp(12)
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 30

            MDLabel:
                id: bank_variable
                markup: True
                text: f'{root.bank_label}'
                halign: 'center' 
                bold: True
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 30

            MDLabel:
                id: bsb_text
                markup: True
                text: 'BSB: '
                halign: 'center'
                font_size: sp(12)
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 30

            MDLabel:
                id: bsb_variable
                markup: True
                text: f'{root.bsb_label}'
                halign: 'center'
                bold: True
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 30

            MDLabel:
                id: account_number_text
                markup: True
                text: 'Acct #: '
                halign: 'center'
                font_size: sp(12) 
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 30

            MDLabel:
                id: account_number_variable
                markup: True
                text: f'{root.account_number_label}'
                halign: 'center'
                bold: True
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 30

            MDLabel:
                id: high_interest_text
                markup: True
                text: 'High Interest: '
                halign: 'center'
                font_size: sp(12)
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 30

            MDLabel:
                id: high_interest_variable
                markup: True
                text: f'{root.high_interest_label}'
                bold: True
                halign: 'center' 
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 30

            MDLabel:
                id: interest_rate_text
                markup: True
                text: 'Interest Rate: '
                halign: 'center'
                font_size: sp(12)
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 30

            MDLabel:
                id: interest_rate_variable
                markup: True
                text: f'{root.interest_rate_label}%'
                bold: True
                halign: 'center'
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 30


       

<AccountsScreen>:

    name: 'accounts_screen'
    accounts_grid: accounts_grid
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: '10dp'
        spacing: '10dp'

        MDLabel:
            text: 'Accounts'
            font_size: sp(32)
            bold: True
            theme_text_color: "Primary"
            size_hint_y: None
            height: dp(40)

        ScrollView:
            do_scroll_x: False
            GridLayout:
                
                id: accounts_grid
                cols: 2#2 if Window.width > 600 else 1
                spacing: '5dp'
                padding: '5dp'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can get what you want by using the `minimum_height` property of the `GridLayout` and the `MDCard`. In your `kv` rule for `AccountWidget`, try something like:

```
<AccountWidget>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: card.height
   
    MDCard:
        id: card
        orientation: 'vertical'
        elevation: 2
        radius: 0
        md_bg_color: [0, 1, 0, 1]
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            rows: 1
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            cols_minimum: {0: self.parent.width * 0.1, 1: self.parent.width * 0.90}
           

            MDLabel:
                id: account_id_variable
                markup: True
                text: f'[size=25][b]{root.id_label}[/b][/size]'
                halign: 'center'
                valign: 'top'
                font_size: sp(22)
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 30
                
            MDLabel:
                id: name
                markup: True
                text: f'[size=25][b]{root.name_label}[/b][/size]'
                halign: 'center'
                valign: 'top'
                font_size: sp(22)
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 30
        
        GridLayout:
            cols: 4
            cols_minimum: {0:self.parent.width*0.15,1:self.parent.width*0.35,2:self.parent.width*0.15,3:self.parent.width*0.35}
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
    .
    .
    .
```

There may also be some dependency on your base class for the `AccountWidget`, but you have not provided that information

Comment: Hey John thanks for your time! There wasn't much going on in my AccountWidget class, just a __init__ which retrieved the account's attribute values, so didn't think it was necessary. 

Your suggestion worked, so I see that my <AccountWidget> needed a height assigned to it, which should be card, then set the cards height to be minimum required to fit, same as the grid layouts. I think I tried almost this before but didn't include the <AccountWidget> size_hint_y and height. Your solution has worked, thank you!